# Log file analyzer for webfarm

Tags: iis, log-files

I'm looking for a log file analyzer software that can collect or read log files from multiple web servers, and aggregates the traffic report for all servers in the farm.

I've been looking at SmarterStats, however my requirements are as follows:

1. I will run the analyser-server on a dedicated machine
2. I will keep the logfiles on each farm-server in a zipped format (dont know if smarterstats support this?)
3. I want to analyze multiple sites on multiple servers, but all sites will have their own individual logfolder per server
4. Preferably the farm-servers can "send" data to the analyzer server, like SmarterStats can do with their "Remote Service", instead of relying on UNC/SAMBA or FTP

Good to have would be email-reporting, or an aggregated summary view with all sites and their total bandwith usage for an administrative user

SmarterStats supports most of the above, but I'm not sure about zipped logfiles or the aggregation of multiple access logs for each day (one for each server in the farm) without needing to copy and rename them, or combining them manually into one file.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend AWstats. It's can merge files from multiple servers, and separate out by vhost into their own individual datafiles/reports. To scp the files periodically, unzip, run the report, and then re-zip the files from a cron job is all a trivial matter. Take a look at the docs I'm sure you'll find it's very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I've used AWStats and Remote Syslog to send logs files from a number of web servers to a dedicated AWStats server.